# Quantum frequency vs classical frequency and Energy dependence

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

I recently realized what seems to be a contradiction in what is called "frequency" 
for light, and would enjoy some clarification of some more educated mind on the matter, thanking you in advance for your time.

At the classical level, light is, in an ideal case, a plane EM wave. The electric field $\mathbf E$ for some light frequency $\nu$ is

$$
\mathbf E(t,\mathbf x) = \mathbf E_\nu \sin(2 \pi\nu t-\mathbf k \mathbf x )
$$
with $\nu=c|\mathbf k|$ and $c$ is the speed of light.

The energy density of the said wave is readily found to be proportional to $|E_\nu|^2$ (magnetic field is omitted for clarity).

Light is described as a wave packet of such waves.

The light spectrum : Radio, visible light, UV , $\gamma$ and all others in between is classified by the value of $\nu$.

In quantum mechanics (or rather QED) one readily defines the energy of a light quantum, a photon, as (having usually put all constants to 1) a frequency $\nu'$.

$$
E= \nu'.
$$

Now to my question.

For sure jumping from photons to classical wave is no light matter (!), but at a first glance, one can reasonably assume that $\nu'$ is linked to $|\mathbf E_\nu|$ due to the energy relations. One would get something like

$$
|\mathbf E_\nu|^2 = \mbox{density of photons} \times \nu'.
$$

However, while discussing radioactive decay for example,  photons of fixed energy i.e. $\nu'$ are often emitted. 
At the same time the same terminology is used. That is we say some $\gamma$ ray is emitted.

In what sense is that to be understood, as it refers to $\nu$ and not $\nu'$ ?

It seems to me that by definition there are NO links between $\nu$ and $\nu'$, even if one introduces wave-packets to do things more rigorously.

Wishing you a good day,

Frédéric

Edit: Thank you for your comments. The reasoning from QED, i.e.   on some state clarifies the identification of $\nu$ and $\nu'$.  I stupidly only recalled the classical average energy over time (which is $\nu$ independent and thus mislead me), where one should really consider the Poynting vector.

Thanks again for your quick comments.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but if it is whether $\nu=\nu'$, then yes, that is correct.

Comment: From the point of view that a QFT starts by setting up the states and the Hamiltonian $H\sim \nu\ a^Ta$, the QED energy is given [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Hamiltonian_of_the_field) and is responsible for both of course $\nu$'s. I.e. $\langle H\rangle\propto \nu$ and "$\mathrm{e}^{-itH}\sim>\sin{(t\nu)}$".

Comment: Maybe you will be interested in this blog entry of Lubos which shows how photons build up the classical electromagnetic wave http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html .